# Does using a non Nexus/Google Play Editon Android device have a higher security risk?

Tags: android, patching, updates

The fact that carriers deploy the latest security updates to Android devices much later than Google does to Google Play Edition and Nexus devices, should we avoid using those devices altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devices that are slower to get security patches are more vulnerable, all things being equal.

However, whether this means you should avoid them depends on your particular threat model and risk tolerance.